# how to make an animation only 1 time on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w8ubh5y/)

```js
countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.count').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false') {
            console.log($(this).text())
            console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
        } else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="count">5.6</span>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>Scroll up and then scroll down again</p>
<span class="count">5.6</span>
```

The problem is, the increasing number animation will run again, if i scroll up and scroll down again. What is the thing that i need to change to stop it? I tried a lot of things, but i am not good at Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a global var as `stopNow = 2` so your animation can only run twice and decrement it when animation runs.

```
var stopNow = 2;
```

Update the countEach function as follows

```
function countEach() {
    $('.count').each(function() {
        //also check stopNow != 0
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false' && stopNow != 0) {
            console.log($(this).text())
            console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
            stopNow = stopNow - 1;  //decrement stopNow
        } else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }
    })
}
```

Here's your updated working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6w8ubh5y/7/

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable. Set it to `false` at the beginning. In the scroll event, check it and if it is still `false`, run the `countEach()` function then change the variable to `true`. Like this:

```
var stop = false;

countEach();
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if(!stop){
    countEach();
    stop = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/6w8ubh5y/5/ ?? 

It do not work. See the result in fiddle, thanks bro

Comment: It counts once you start scrolling (but you don't see it because you will still haven't reached the bottom counter and you have an issue with your `showOnScreen` function that's preventing the top counter from counting). How do you want it to work? Do you want it to count when your reach the bottom and then stop? If so, use Raj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event binding code from:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    countEach()
})
```

to

```
$(window).on('scroll', countEach);
```

and change countEach function like this...

```
function countEach() {
    $('.count').each(function() {
        ...
    });

    $(window).off('scroll', countEach); // add this line
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/6w8ubh5y/6/

But then the number animate  before scroll